# Django: list all objects with non unique field

Tags: django, django-queryset

If I have the following Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

how do I list all objects that have a non unique last_name field? For example, if there are 20 objects that all have the last_name 'Smith', they would be listed. However, if only one object had the last_name 'Euler' it would not be included in the list.

Comment: I think, this is not task for Django ORM. Try raw sql and check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way with 2 queries:

```
non_unique_last_names = (Person.objects
    .values_list('last_name', flat=True)
    .annotate(last_name_count=Count('last_name'))
    .filter(last_name_count__gt=1))

non_unique_person_objects = Person.objects.filter(last_name__in=non_unique_last_names)
```

Comment: Where does the Count class come from?

Comment: @Jura `from django.db.models import Count`

Answer (score 5):

You will probably want to cast `list` to `non_unique_last_names` to fight `OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1`

So, to those who will use this code, the right version is:

```
from django.db.models import Count
non_unique_last_names = (Person.objects
    .values_list('last_name', flat=True)
    .annotate(last_name_count=Count('last_name'))
    .filter(last_name_count__gt=1))

non_unique_person_objects = Person.objects.filter(last_name__in=list(non_unique_last_names))
```