# Extract data from large database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query e-mails from a database that holds approx 170,000 rows of data. I have a basic mysql php script that works, but only will show the first 34,000 or so data.

My ultimate goal is to purge a large database of duplicates. How could I go about this?

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM guess ORDER BY id";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
?>

First

<?php
$b=30000;
while ($b < 60000) {
    $id = mysql_result($result,$b,"id");
    $email = mysql_result($result,$b,"Email");
?>

<?php echo $b;  ?>. <?php echo $email ?> <br />
<?php $nummer++;   $b++; } ?> 

second
```

By using the above, I was going to store all the rows that contain an email in a php array.

Then, write write a script that will find duplicate emails and strip them. Finally, print the code in a browser, copy and paste in text and upload to my chimpmail.

Comment: Show your code so we don't guess what is going on.

Comment: Do you really need all of the data in code, or are you just looking to export it to a file?  MySQL for example has a utility called 'mysqldump' that might be easier for you.

Comment: hi, the reason being is that there are a lot of duplicate emails. So I was going to store all the rows that contain an email in a php array. Then write write a script hat will find duplicate emails and strip then. Then print the code in a browser, copy and paste in text and upload to my chimpmail.

Comment: You can follow this question for your need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql

Comment: I've made some edits to your question for formatting, and moved your subsequent comments into the question for clarification. Please double check my edits and improve them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

An idea which is probably not a good one but whatever... if you only read 34K data at once and you know the total amount of rows, using LIMIT in your query could be a solution.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure of that technique, I'll look it up. Thanks