# SQL to see all duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a massive table with thousands of rows. Each row has a unique path. For example:

```
electronics/samsung/tv/lcd-23384
electronics/philips/tv/lcd-12ger
etc...
```

The problem is, a recent query was executed incorrectly, resulting in some of the fields having duplicate paths. So, what i want to know is, is there a query I can execute to show ALL the duplicates? In other words, if I have this:

```
ID     | PATH 
1      | path_1
2      | path_2
3      | path_3
4      | path_3
5      | path_3
6      | path_4
7      | path_4
8      | path_5
9      | path_6
```

I want this result:

```
ID     | PATH 
3      | path_3
4      | path_3
5      | path_3
6      | path_4
7      | path_4
```

Notice that all NON-duplicates have been removed. Ie.... these ones:

```
ID     | PATH 
1      | path_1
2      | path_2
8      | path_5
9      | path_6
```

What SQL query can accomplish this?

Comment: see this::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql

Comment: @Sudhir: That doesn't do exactly what the OP wants, as one then needs to reexpand the groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT PATH FROM mytable GROUP BY PATH HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dupes
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b757/1/0).

---

To perform the update you request in the comments below:

```
UPDATE mytable NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT PATH FROM mytable GROUP BY PATH HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dupes, (SELECT @r:=0) init
SET mytable.PATH = CONCAT(PATH, '-', @r:=@r+1);
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73d10/1/0).

Comment: Awesome... is there a way to update all duplicates so the paths end in  "-1", "-2", "-3" etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, substitute needed table and column values:

```
SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(*) TotalCount
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY YourColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see all duplicates  by using such query

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Path in
  (SELECT PATH
   FROM YourTable
   GROUP BY PATH
   HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

What kind of rows do you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

It will give you all duplicate results

```
select column_name, count(column_name) occurrence from table_name 
group by column_name having count(column_name) > 1;
```

And if you want to get all non duplicate results..

```
select column_name, count(column_name) occurrence from table_name 
group by column_name having count(column_name) = 1;
```