# Select and display only duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

This question is pretty simple I for some reason can't get the proper result to display only the duplicate records

```
Table   : Paypal_ipn_orders
id                              payer_email
1                               susan@gmail.com
2                               ryan@gmail.com   
3                               susan@gmail.com
4                               steve@gmail.com
5                               steve@gmail.com

SELECT id, COUNT( payer_email ) `tot`
FROM paypal_ipn_orders
GROUP BY payer_email
HAVING `tot` >1
```

sample output

```
id       tot
1         2
4         2
```

expected output

```
id       payer_email 
1        susan@gmail.com
3        susan@gmail.com
4        steve@gmail.com
5        steve@gmail.com
```

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
SELECT id, payer_email
FROM paypal_ipn_orders
WHERE payer_email IN (
    SELECT payer_email
    FROM paypal_ipn_orders
    GROUP BY payer_email
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d708/2)

Comment: that returns this
`unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE
unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE`
and `Showing rows 0 - -1 ( 0 total, Query took 39.6457 sec)`

Comment: @user1542036 That has nothing to do with this query. It is correct (check the sqlfidddle). Do a Google search on your error.

Comment: the only thing I find is it appears to be a problem with the particular version of phpmyadmin? I'm running 3.4.1 so upgrading to the newest version should fix it?

Comment: very slow in large table.

Comment: Thanks mate, you just saved me lots of time.

Comment: Yes it is slow in a large table or complex query we should use join (inner join) instead of this

Comment: See [Timo's answer using Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21408164/199364) for better performance.

Answer (score 18):

The `IN` was too slow in my situation (180 secs)

So I used a `JOIN` instead (0.3 secs)

```
SELECT i.id, i.payer_email
FROM paypal_ipn_orders i
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT payer_email
    FROM paypal_ipn_orders 
    GROUP BY payer_email
    HAVING COUNT( id ) > 1
) j ON i.payer_email=j.payer_email
```

Comment: Use

SELECT i.id, i.payer_email
FROM paypal_ipn_orders i 

otherwise it will show ambiguous error

Answer (score 7):

here is the simple example :

```
select <duplicate_column_name> from <table_name> group by <duplicate_column_name> having count(*)>=2
```

It will definitly work. :)

Comment: this is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of all duplicate rows from table:

```
Select * from TABLE1 where PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN NOT IN ( SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY DUP_COLUMN_NAME having (count(*) >= 1))
```

Comment: By far the fastest, but you need to remove the "=" from count(*) >= 1 because it will take the ids that exists only once too.

Comment: Stack Overflow needs to allow <6 character edits. >= is simply wrong here.

Comment: @Incognito - NO, the purpose of `>=` is to INCLUDE non-duplicate rows; then `NOT IN` returns the "extra" rows when there are duplicates. Note that this is slighly different than OP's request, which would list BOTH rows of each duplicate. If you do `>`, then `NOT IN` will give you many non-duplicate rows. In that case, if used the resulting IDs to delete duplicates, the result would be disastrous!

Answer (score 1):

Hi above answer will not work if I want to select one or more column value which is not same or may be same for both row data

For Ex. I want to select username, birth date also. But in database is username is not   duplicate but birth date will be duplicate then this solution will not work.

For this use this solution 
Need to take self join on same table/

```
SELECT  
    distinct(p1.id),  p1.payer_email , p1.username, p1.birth_date

FROM 
    paypal_ipn_orders AS p1 

INNER JOIN paypal_ipn_orders AS p2 

ON p1.payer_email=p2.payer_email

WHERE 

p1.birth_date=p2.birth_date
```

Above query will return all records having same email_id and same birth date

Comment: Minor nit: Likely faster to replace `WHERE` with `AND` so the filtering is done during the `INNER JOIN`, rather than afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This works the fastest for me

```
SELECT
    primary_key
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    primary_key NOT IN (
        SELECT
            primary_key
        FROM
            table_name
        GROUP BY
            column_name
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) = 1
    );
```

Comment: This will not give the correct result as you are excluding the duplicate record change NOT IN to IN

Comment: @Abhinavbhardwaj - I've tested this answer, and it works. The `inner SELECT` finds keys of all NOT-DUPLICATED column values. Then `NOT IN` excludes those, thereby finding all DUPLICATES.

Answer (score 1):

use  this code

```
 SELECT *  
    FROM  paypal_ipn_orders 
    GROUP BY  payer_email  
    HAVING COUNT( payer_email) >1
```

Comment: Not correct. will show only one row per GROUP BY value. What happens if there are THREE with same email?  This will only list ONE of them. (If that is rare, could run this again, to catch any remaining duplicates. Repeat until zero rows returned.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, payer_email FROM paypal_ipn_orders
WHERE payer_email IN (
    SELECT payer_email FROM papypal_ipn_orders GROUP BY payer_email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: this also returns the samething as the others

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21408164/4152012), though I used a temporary table instead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates (
    SELECT payer_email
    FROM paypal_ipn_orders
    GROUP BY payer_email
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
);
SELECT id, payer_email
FROM paypal_ipn_orders AS p
INNER JOIN duplicates AS d ON d.payer_email=p.payer_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` t1 join `table` t2 WHERE (t1.name=t2.name) && (t1.id!=t2.id)
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution to the problem? You may also use the code indentation feature of the editor to highlight the SQL (four spaces).

Answer (score -1):

I think this way is the simplier. The output displays the id and the payer's email where the payer's email is in more than one record at this table. The results are sorted by id.

```
    SELECT id, payer_email
    FROM paypal_ipn_orders
    WHERE COUNT( payer_email )>1
    SORT BY id;
```

Comment: MySQL response: Not a valid query: "Invalid use of a group function". It makes no sense to use COUNT like this, without GROUP BY.

Answer (score -2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT( payer_email ) `tot`
FROM paypal_ipn_orders
GROUP BY id
HAVING `tot` >1
```

Does it help?