# MySQL query returning a negative row number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Well this is an odd thing for sure. Am using MySQL to display a series of alerts, and the query I'm using separates by way of what level the alert is. The table has five columns, but the one being used here is the level column (alert level: 1 - normal; 2 - moderate; 3 - high). ID is used to only display the oddity with the query.

The weird thing is when I run this query, it displays normally:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerttxt` ORDER BY level ASC
```

It loses an entry on the web page when I switch the order, but shows all the rows in PHPMyAdmin...which is odd itself:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerttxt` ORDER BY level DESC
```

But the minute I add in an extra element:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerttxt` WHERE level = '2' ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Things go haywire. I ran this same query in PHPMyAdmin, also using ORDER BY ID DESC, and the return was as follows:

```
    Showing rows 0 - -1
```

I've never seen this before and am not quite sure how to fix it. Anyone else seen this before and be able to fix it? Thanks, all!

Added 8/31/12 - for grumpy

```
ID  level   system     status                           restoretime
0   2       MyISU      System is functioning normally   NULL
1   2       Network    System is functioning normally   NULL
2   1       Blackboard System is functioning normally   NULL
3   3       Email      System is functioning normally   NULL
4   1       Banner     System is functioning normally   NULL
```

and the structure:

```
Column      |  Type         | Null  |  Default
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ID             int(11)        No         
level          varchar(3)     No       1     
system         varchar(255)   No         
status         varchar(755)   No       System is functioning normally    
restoretime    text           Yes      NULL
```

Comment: What mysql function are you using to query your sql?

Comment: what's the type of your `level` column ?

Comment: doesnt showing rows 0-1  mean in phpmyadmin  showing 2 results?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array...haven't tried mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: @jidma - INT with no auto increment

Comment: @grumpy - yes, but it's showing 0- -1, it's clearly a negative number

Comment: post structure of table with some data.

Comment: @synk in this case can you try `WHERE level = 2 ORDER BY ID ASC` without the quotes around 2 ?

Comment: @jidma - i actually tried both with and without quotes. neither work.

Comment: i don't know if this has anything to do with it, but our system admin recently upgraded everything so our current version is 5.0.45.

Comment: @grumpy - just edited my original with the tables you were asking for. first one is the display, the second is the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's a bug in phpMyAdmin, as search for that error message and comments for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694832/1229023) seem to confirm. And it's quite easy to check: run the queries you've asked for in MySQL console.

Comment: Sure looks like it. Did a little more research and found that the version of PHPMyAdmin we're running is 3.5.0 and the latest stable release is up 3.5.2.2, so it seems to be exactly what you were assuming: a bug. Sent our server admin an email to upgrade it, so as soon as he does that, I'll post another comment with how things went. Thanks!