# How find values not duplicate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve all the values from a table in which email ID are not repeated. But when I run below query the execution goes into infinite in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS 
WHERE EMAIL IN ( 
     SELECT EMAIL 
     FROM USERS 
     GROUP BY EMAIL 
     HAVING COUNT(1) = 1)
```

I don't understand why this query is going into infinite and is there any other way to get same data without inner query.

I also referred this link in which duplicate values are found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as-is, but you might try to rewrite it to a Join instead, MySQL's optimizer is not that clever :-)

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM USERS AS u
JOIN ( SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS GROUP BY EMAIL HAVING COUNT(1) = 1) AS dt
ON u.EMAIL = dt.email
```

Comment: Thank You very much this solved my problem I was looking out with join because after this join I have other join with some other tables.

Answer (score 3):

This is one case where the MySQL extension on `group by` comes in handy.  You can do this query as:

```
select u.*
from users u
group by email
having count(*) = 1;
```

The MySQL extension allows you to include columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  The values come from arbitrary (the documentation says **indeterminate**) matching rows.  Because of the `having` clause, only one row matches, so the values will come from that row.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem ?

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL IN 
  ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL
    FROM USERS 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM USERS group by email
```

Probably the simplest answer, I tried it on my database and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

use complex join for solve this problem.

```
SELECT u1.* FROM users AS u1
INNER JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.email=u2.email AND u1.ID<>u2.ID
```