# Find duplicate record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named property ,structured like this.

```
property_id | ListingKey | name
1             abkjhj-123   abc
2             abkjhj-123   abc1
3             abkjhj-124   abc4
```

I want duplicate records based on ListingKey. I write this query but not sure is this correct or not?

```
SELECT a.property_id
FROM property a
INNER JOIN property b ON a.property_id = b.property_id
WHERE a.ListingKey <> b.ListingKey
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the self join with a `Having` clause:

```
SELECT a.ListingKey 
FROM property a
GROUP BY a.ListingKey
HAVING COUNT(a.property_id) > 1;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65173/1)

Update : If you want a list of all the ids in the Duplicate as well:

```
SELECT a.ListingKey, GROUP_CONCAT(a.property_id)
FROM property a
GROUP BY a.ListingKey
HAVING COUNT(a.property_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct.  Here is another method:

```
select p.*
from property p
where exists (select 1
              from property p2
              where p2.listingkey = p.listingkey and p2.property_id <> p.property_id
             );
```

If you care about performance, add an index on `property(listingkey, property_id)`.