# How to write a query to get the person name displays more than twice in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

If the table shows like below.

```
Number     Name
 1          A 
 2          A
 3          B
 4          C
 5          D
```

So for the example, I want to get the A. 
Should I use join here?

Comment: `SELECT Name FROM table GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: you can simply use a where clause .. if i understood your requirement  correctly

Comment: You will find your answer here:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/688551/1578380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by simply to get the same.

```
Select Name from [User] group by Name having COUNT(Name ) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT Name,COUNT(*) AS[sum]
                FROM[yourtable]
                GROUP BY Name
                               ) X
WHERE X.[sum] > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
SELECT DISTINCT names
```

It will show unique value of table has more than a value.

Hope this help !

Comment: How could this be an answer ? Read the question pal !

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and having to get your required result. You can use also a count to see the how many times same name there 
SELECT COUNT(name) AS total,name FROM tablename GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) >2

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join

```
SELECT a.* FROM tbname AS a
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT NAME FROM tbname GROUP BY NAME
         HAVING COUNT(NAME)>1
) AS b ON a.name=b.name
```