# SQL - Join two distinct result sets

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm new with SQL and just had my first assignment.

I have the following requirements:
Given is a database of two tables. The first one contains information about the user, like a unique ID per user, the phone number and the city. ID and phone number consist only of numeric digits. The second table contains data about so called „credits“, which a user can own. Again there is a column for the unique user ID, but also the number, the date and the type of credits. A user can have none, one or several entries in the credit table.

I'm still now sure if I got right the part where a user can have none, one or several entries in the credit table. I created these two tables:

```
CREATE table user
(

 user_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,

 user_phone_number INT NOT NULL,

 user_city VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
 );

CREATE table credit
(
 credit_user_id INT FOREIGN KEY (user_id),

 credit_date date,

 credit_number double,

 credit_type char(10),

   CONSTRAINT chk_type CHECK (credit_type in ('None','A','B','C')),
 );
```

After creating this, I was asked the following questions:

a) The phone number of all users, who own credits of type „A“

```
SELECT user_phone_number 
FROM user, credit
WHERE credit_type = 'A';
```

b) Like a), but additionally the credit_number of the credits is smaller than 2 or greater than 4

```
SELECT user_phone_number
FROM user, credit
WHERE (credit_type ='A')
AND (credit_number < 2 OR credit_number > 4);
```

C) Like a), but additionally the users also own credits of at least one other type.

```
SELECT user_phone_number 
FROM user, credit
WHERE credit_type = 'A'
AND (
SELECT DISTINCT c1.credit_type FROM credit AS c1
JOIN credit a1 ON (c1.credit_type=a1.credit_type)
JOIN credit a2 ON (c1.credit_type=a2.credit_type)
WHERE a2.credit_type<>a1.credit_type);
```

My problem is that I can't make letter C work, even if both selects seem to work separately. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you teach yourself the basics of SQL before tackling something. An on line search with the keywords "SQL Beginner's Tutorial" will bring you at least half a dozen possibilities to train yourself on-line on the basics. After that, you'll see what's wrong with your approach.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  All your answers are wrong.  Hence, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Comment: This is actually from an online SQL basics course I'm taking to learn more, I will continue searching for more tutorials. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want in C) but many things to say.

- You should't use a database name like 'user' because it can be ambigous (reserved word) for SGBD.
- You should prefer 'join' instead of 'from table1, table2' and / or mix both.
  [Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338)
- You've got ';' in your request in C) which must be only for specify the end of your request.
- You can use nested resquet but not like that, not directly after 'AND' because AND is for condition like a comparison. You've got many possibilites : in select fied, after 'FROM', after 'IN', with join, in condition...
  [Quick search on google.](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-subqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

From another post:

> PRIMARY KEY(x), UNIQUE(x) -- Since a PRIMARY KEY is by definition (in MySQL) UNIQUE...

Since you want to find everyone with 2 kinds of credit, I'd try to make a query like if I was looking for duplicates, here's two ways to do that:
With subquery
[Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)
Without
[Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Here's an approach using the nested query style you're trying to use. I've used explicit JOINs rather than `FROM user, credit` in the `FROM` clause, because this makes it clearer that it's a join.

Say your `users` table looks like this -

```
user_id     user_phone_number   user_city
6           75771               Leeds
7           75772               Wakefield
8           75773               Dewsbury
9           75774               Heckmondwike
10          75775               Huddersfield
```

And your `credit` table looks like this -

```
credit_user_id      credit_date     credit_number   credit_type
7                   2017-02-13      2               A
7                   2017-02-13      2               B
6                   2017-02-13      2               A
8                   2017-02-13      4               B
```

The nested query in the `AND` clause returns records where the `credit_type` is **not** `A`, and the `WHERE` in the main query selects all records where the `credit_type` is **is** `A`, so if the record appears in both, the user must have two types of credit -

```
SELECT user_phone_number 
FROM [user] AS u
JOIN credit AS c ON u.user_id = c.credit_user_id
WHERE credit_type = 'A'
AND u.user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM [user] AS u
    JOIN credit AS c ON u.user_id = c.credit_user_id
    WHERE credit_type <> 'A')
```

As you can see from the tables, the user with the `id` of `7` has credit both of type `A` and `B`, so we end up with -

```
user_phone_number
75772
```

I'd agree that you might want to consider some of the points others have raised above, but won't repeat.