# SQL query, to display duplicate values with all the columns

Tags: mysql

please correct the below sql query. 
Here columns are dynamic. 
So i have to user * only. 
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Id IN ('abc','123') GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: "columns are dynamic" You're asking us to fix the wrong thing then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/688549/3664960 has so many variants of finding duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the column corresponding to the selected IDs:

```
select *
from test_table
where id in (
        select id
        from test_table
        where Id in ('abc','123')
        group by Id
        having COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

For only Id:

```
select id
from test_table
where Id in ('abc','123')
group by Id
having COUNT(*) > 1
```