# count duplicate data in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Is there a way to count the duplicate data from mysql and 
display it to a bar chart, Im trying to make a attendance report 
using morris bar chart.

here my sample code:

```
<html >
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php 

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sa");
    $query = "SELECT year,  count(*) as course FROM test group by  year,course order by year ASC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $chart_data = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $chart_data .= "{ year:'".$row["year"]."', course:".$row["course"]."}, ";
    }
    $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
    ?>
```

and this is my javascript:

```
<script>
Morris.Bar({
 element : 'chart',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
 xkey:'year',
 ykeys:['course','course','course','course','course'],
 labels:['BSIT','BSHRM','BSCS','BSTM','ABCOMM'],
 hideHover:'auto',
   xLabelAngle: '60',
  verticalGrid: true,
  resize:true,
   barColors: ['red','blue','green','yellow','black'],
      gridTextSize: 12



});
</script>
```

this is my database:

[image]

UPDATED: and this is my output so  far:
[image]

[image]
as you can see in my output all courses have same value for example
the two 2018-07-12 the output should be based on my database is for BSIT = 3 
 the rest is zero value same with the other  2018-07-12 the output should be BSHRM =1 and the rest is zero value, is there a way to achieve that?, Hope you can help me.

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY year, course`.

Comment: `SELECT year , course ,  count(*) as course` you're reusing the same name `course` for the course name and the count.

Comment: i tried  this code SELECT year , count(*) as course FROM test group by  year, course but still don't work.

Comment: `SELECT year, course, count(*) as count`

Comment: when i tried your query my bar chart disappear

Comment: Create a query to obtain duplicate items, then use the data however you please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql <- how to query for duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your query:

First, the alias `COUNT(*) AS course` reuses the column name as the alias. You need to give it a different name.

Second, you left `course` out of the grouping, so you're combining the counts of all courses in your results.

It should be:

```
$query = "SELECT year , course ,  count(*) as count FROM test group by  year, course order by year ASC ";
```

Each course will then be in a different row of the results, you'll need to regroup when you process the results.

You also shouldn't create JSON by concatenating strings. Put the results in an array and use `json_encode()`.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $results[$row['year']]['year'] = $row['year'];
    $results[$row['year']][$row['course']] = $row['count'];
}
$chart_data = json_encode(array_values($results));
```

This method uses the course names as the keys in the JSON, not `course1`, `course2`, etc. So you need to change

```
ykeys:['course','course','course','course','course'],
```

to:

```
ykeys:['BSIT','BSHRM','BSCS','BSTM','ABCOMM'],
```

The JSON in `$chart_data` already includes the square brackets around the array, so you don't need to add it around the echo. Use:

```
data: <?php echo $chart_data; ?>,
```

Comment: i tried your code , the bar chart is not displaying only the label for bar chart is displaying with no data counted.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to display the results properly.

Comment: Can you post `$chart_data`?

Comment: post the output ?

Comment: yeah, the output of `echo $chart_data;`

Comment: i post above the output of $chart_data;

Comment: All I see is a new image of the empty graph, where is the raw data?

Comment: this is the output of when i echo $chart_data  = [{"year":"2018-07-08","ABCOMM":"1"},{"year":"2018-07-09","BSIT":"1"},{"year":"2018-07-10","BSCS":"1","BSHRM":"1","BSTM":"1"},{"year":"2018-07-11","BSCS":"1","BSHRM":"1"},{"year":"2018-07-12","ABCOMM":"1","BSIT":"3"}]

Comment: Just noticed that you have unnecessary brackets in `data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],`. The brackets are already in `$chart_data`.

Comment: OMG, i don't noticed the bracket all this time. when i removed the bracket it shows the graph and data that i needed to display. thank you Barmar  :)