# Finding duplicate records in table along with its related other duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find duplicate records in my table and I have the code to show the records but I need to modify it so that it also shows the other duplicate record. My example table is the following:

[TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcumH.png)

As you can see, the table (t_sen) contains duplicate records and I have this code to display the duplicate records:

```
    $sql = "SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, TEXT FROM t_sen GROUP BY TEXT having count(*) >= 2";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

        foreach($row as $column => $value){
            print "$column: $value <br>";
        }

        print "<br>";
    }
```

The output that I get is:

```
ID  |   PARA_NUMBER  |  TEXT
----------------------------
3   |   1            |  is
7   |   2            |  live
```

However the output that I want is:

```
ID  |   PARA_NUMBER  |  TEXT
----------------------------
3   |   1            |  is
4   |   1            |  is

7   |   2            |  live
8   |   2            |  live
```

I want it to show the other duplicate column also within the defined PARA_NUMBER. So an example (made up?) query would be something like:

```
SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, TEXT FROM t_sen (WITHIN PARA_NUMBER = 1) having count(*) >= 2
```

So the output should be:

```
ID  |   PARA_NUMBER  |  TEXT
----------------------------
3   |   1            |  is
4   |   1            |  is
```

But it would be much better if I don't have to repeat the query for every single PARA_NUMBER as there are many numbers and just one query can display all the duplicate records.

Hope I'm clear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql) - look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596921/7926064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It uses a subquery to find all the values of `TEXT` which have duplicates in the table, and JOINs that to the original table so that you can display each entry which has the duplicate `TEXT` value.

```
SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, t1.TEXT FROM
t_sen t1
JOIN (SELECT TEXT
      FROM t_sen
      GROUP BY TEXT
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2) t2
ON t1.TEXT = t2.TEXT
```

Output:

```
ID  PARA_NUMBER     TEXT
3   1               is
4   1               is
7   2               live
8   2               live
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd3e4b/6)

If you only want to get the duplicates in `PARA_NUMBER` 1, for example, just add a `WHERE` clause to the end:

```
SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, t1.TEXT FROM
t_sen t1
JOIN (SELECT TEXT
      FROM t_sen
      GROUP BY TEXT
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2) t2
ON t1.TEXT = t2.TEXT
WHERE PARA_NUMBER = 1
```

Output:

```
ID  PARA_NUMBER     TEXT
3   1               is
4   1               is
```

**Edit**

Based on OPs requirement to be able to edit the rows in phpMyAdmin, a query with a `JOIN` will not solve the problem. Instead a query such as this one is required:

```
SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, t1.TEXT FROM
t_sen t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM t_sen t2
              WHERE t2.PARA_NUMBER = t1.PARA_NUMBER AND
                    t2.TEXT = t1.TEXT AND
                    t2.ID != t1.ID)
```

Output:

```
ID  PARA_NUMBER     TEXT
3   1               is
4   1               is
7   2               live
8   2               live
```

Comment: This worked thanks a lot. But any idea why when I put this query in phpMyAdmin, it tells me that I cannot edit anything because there’s no unique column when clearly I have the ID column set as unique, index and primary?

Comment: That's because the result table (the joined table) doesn't have a unique key. It's nothing to worry about.

Comment: No I mean I need to edit the results that show up when I use this query at phpMyAdmin directly. But I cannot because of what you’ve said. So how can I solve this?

Comment: Hi MARWAN, I've added a different form of the query to my answer that will allow you to edit in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I always use grouping to find duplicates. My suggestion:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-', ID, PARA_NUMBER, TEXT)) AS data FROM t_sen GROUP BY PARA_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

This will give you results in this format:

```
| data          |
| 3-1-is,4-1-is |
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.PARA_NUMBER, t.TEXT FROM
(SELECT TEXT FROM t_sen GROUP BY TEXT having count(*) >= 2) as duplicateValue
LEFT JOIN t_sen as t on duplicateValue.TEXT = t.TEXT
WHERE 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Left Join

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    t_sen AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    t_sen AS t2 ON t1.ID != t2.ID AND t1.PARA_NUMBER = t2.PARA_NUMBER 
WHERE
    t2.ID IS NOT NULL
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWgcgx7HxYVmvui7tJZ1PB/3)

- `t1.ID != t2.ID` excludes matching the same row in both tables (well both sides of the join)
- `t1.PARA_NUMBER = t2.PARA_NUMBER` joins the tales on the duplicate number
- `WHERE t2.ID IS NOT NULL` excludes records that are not duplicate.

you could also use `TEXT` which is a really bad name for a column, by adding that to the ON part of the join, in addition or in place of `PARA_NUMBER` as you needs require.

Just for posterity

```
CREATE TABLE t_sen (
    ID INT,
    PARA_NUMBER  INT,
    `TEXT` VARCHAR(20)
);

#non duplate
INSERT INTO t_sen  (ID, PARA_NUMBER, `TEXT`)VALUES(1,10,'the');
#duplicates
INSERT INTO t_sen  (ID, PARA_NUMBER, `TEXT`)VALUES(3,1,'is');
INSERT INTO t_sen  (ID, PARA_NUMBER, `TEXT`)VALUES(4,1,'is');
INSERT INTO t_sen  (ID, PARA_NUMBER, `TEXT`)VALUES(7,2,'live');
INSERT INTO t_sen  (ID, PARA_NUMBER, `TEXT`)VALUES(8,2,'live');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should print all the records that have duplicate on PARA_NUMBER and TEXT field-

SELECT ID, PARA_NUMBER, TEXT FROM t_sen WHERE (PARA_NUMBER, TEXT) IN 
(SELECT PARA_NUMBER, TEXT FROM t_sen GROUP BY PARA_NUMBER, TEXT having count(*) >= 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer that has solved your problem.