# How can I fetch user id which have two values

Tags: mysql

For example, I have 2 tables **skill table** and **user table**

I need to fetch the only `user_id` from table **user** who has both `skill_id` **1041** and **47**.

How to fetch when inner join **where** `job_id =39`.

Skill table

```
---------------------------------------
| id | job_id | skill_id | profile
---------------------------------------
| 1 |   39   |  1041    | intermediate
---------------------------------------
| 2 |   39   |  47      | intermediate
---------------------------------------
```

User table

```
---------------------------------------
| id | user_id | skill_id | profile 
---------------------------------------
| 1 |   212   |  1041    | intermediate
---------------------------------------
| 2 |   212   |  1218    | intermediate
---------------------------------------
| 3 |   213   |  1041    | intermediate
---------------------------------------
| 4 |   213   |  47      | intermediate
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: using **`and`**

Comment: 'and' wont work and would give empty result

Comment: then there is no rows. simple :)

Comment: i think this is what though SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE skill_id = 1041 and skill_id=47. this is user is a mapping table  i need to get user who have both skill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
 select user_id,count(skill_id) from user_table
    where skill_id  in (1041,47)
    group by user_id
    having count(skill_id)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the skill table two time in join

```
select s1.user_id 
from skill s1  
inner join skill s2 on s1.user_id = s2.user_id 
    and s1.skill_id =1014 
    and s2.skill_id = 47
```

Comment: and wont work even in user table alone hope this is what u mean SELECT * FROM `jh_job_user_skill` WHERE skill_id = 1041 and skill_id=47