# To Display Duplicate Records Only...in only one column which having so duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, oracle

A table having duplicate record columns... I need to just show how many duplicate values present in that particular column...not unique values...Only Duplicate values should be displayed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Search for mysql duplicates - lots of stuff out there..

Answer (score 1):

Do a `count` with `groupby`, and then filter the ones that have duplicates with `having your_count_column > 1`