# Postgres - how to get proper count with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

Sorry as a newcomer to sql (postgres in this case) I can't tease out the right answer from similar questions. So here's an example

I have two tables:

records:

```
id    |  status 
----------------
1     | open
2     | open
3     | close
4     | open
```

events:

```
id    | record_id  | role   | something_else
---------------------------------------------
1     |  2         | admin  | stringA
2     |  1         | user   | stringB
3     |  4         | admin  | stringC
4     |  2         | admin  | stringD
5     |  2         | admin  | stringE
6     |  2         | user   | stringF  
7     |  3         | user   | stringG
```

I basically would like to have a count(status) that reflects how many records have at least one events.role = 'admin' in the events table

in the above example it would be:

```
status | count 
---------------
open   |   2
close  |   0
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

Comment: not really - because my question is not about finding duplicate values, but mainly to joining tables and getting only 1 count on a first table field based on multiple hits in another table.

Answer (score 2):

No need for nested queries. You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select r.status, count(distinct r.id) filter(where e.role = 'admin') cnt
from records r
inner join events e on e.record_id = r.id
group by r.status
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6fd1d7b2e6acdae53a4c819c95c134a3)**:

```
status | cnt
:----- | --:
close  |   0
open   |   2
```

Comment: Thanks! this solution looks very elegant, but I wonder how the argument that Gordon Linoff makes below about the join duplicating the number of rows would affect the response time as the database grows in size

Answer (score 2):

> I basically would like to have a count(status) that reflects how many records have at least one events.role = 'admin' in the events table.

I would suggest:

```
select r.status, count(*) filter (where has_admin)
from (select r.*, 
             (exists (select 1 from events e where e.record_id = r.id and e.role = 'admin')) as has_admin
      from records r
     ) r
group by r.status;
```

For your small data sample, the difference between `exists` and a `join` doesn't matter.  With more data, though, the `exists` does not multiply the number of rows, which should make it a bit faster.  Also, this guarantees that all statuses are included, even those with no events.